# Is there any logical container tag in HTMl that I can use for grouping?

Tags: html, containers

I need something not visible in page, something that don't have any borders and something that doesn't affect page rendering at all.
I need this for a mass hiding or showing things inside, like `document.getElementById("asd").innerHTML = "blah bla blah and some buttons and etc";`

I want it's tag borders to not be shown on the page or changed the rendering at all.

For example, I want the rendered result to be same for:

```
<div>
    asd
    <input type = "button" value = "dsa" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>zxc</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    qwe
</div>
```

and:

```
<div>
    asd
    <something id = "asd">
        <input type = "button" value = "dsa" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>zxc</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </something>
    qwe
</div>
```

The div is bad, because it have a borders and renders from new line in html page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asd</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        asd<div id = "test_div" style = "display: none;">dsa</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**dsa** also became invisible

Comment: `<div>` don't have `border` by default in any browser I know of (are you talking about `margin` or `padding`?).  
If you want an inline element, you can use `<span>`.  
I also suggest you look into styling things the way you want with CSS.

Comment: Check out the `<data>` tag.

Comment: I do mean logical border, but not the visible one. div have the border, no matter if it visible or no.

Comment: They are right on CSS.  Add `display:none;` and whatever tag is invisible, meeting your requirements.

Comment: `display:none;` did make all contained things invisible too, which i don't want to happen.

Comment: `<data>` is cool thing. Thanks. Make it as answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: `<span>` works too. Weird, I can't find description for `<data>` tag. IS this standard one? which is better to use?

Comment: The question title does not match the question body at all, and neither of them is a sufficiently well defined question to be answered meaningfully. If you want a page to contain something invisible, it is crucial what you expect or want such content to “do”.

Comment: I don't want anything invisible, as I told I need this for grouping purpose, but the container itself should not be visible on the page or affect it's rendering in any way. **table** bad, **div** pad, **data** and **span** cool.

Comment: @Kosmos, you should clarify the question by editing it (including its title), not in comments. Explaining the use case (the practical purpose) might help in guessing what you really mean.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I don't see there anything that should be edited :( The topic says the purpose - **for grouping**. The first lines of question says the reqs of tag: **not visible in page, something that don't have any borders and something that doesn't affect page rendering at all** and even usage example included. But, ok. I guess I should enter additional things.

Comment: @Kosmos, “for grouping” is not a use case. You group things for some purpose. A use case is something practical and real where things are done. And several inaccuracies in the question have been pointed out (e.g., `div` elements have no default border). And by “not visible”, you must mean something different from what you say.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Ok, by **not visible** I do mean the container tag invisible and don't affect rendering in anyway, but it's content visible. div always have logical border, not matter of it visible or no.

Comment: The purpose is... I need it for dynamic replacing content of this tag I looking for, so it's update will not cause html page additional changes related to container border position change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of the question: You would like to use an HTML element, inside the `body` element, so that it can include various elements, including block elements like tables, so that the page is rendered as if the element’s start and end tag were not there. That is, as if the element were replaced by its content. In particular, it should not cause any line break.

There is no such element in HTML. What come closest are `ins` and `del`. They might come close enough, as their only default effect on rendering is that text content is underlined or overstruck, respectively (browsers implement this inconsistently for text inside block elements), and these effects are easily cancelled out, with the usual CSS caveats:

```
ins, del { text-decoration: none; }
```

The reason why this works (and is valid HTML) is that these elements have “transparent content model”. E.g., an [`ins` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/edits.html#the-ins-element) may contain anything that would be allowed in the context where the element appears.

Whether it is logical to use such elements is debatable, but in fact, `ins` (for inserted content) might even be regarded as logical to use, depending on what you are doing.

Beware that some user agents or assistive software may (at least in future) implement these elements in a manner that reflects their defined meaning. For example, a speech browser might speak “inserted text” and “end of inserted text” before and after an `ins` element.

To some extent, the `a` element (without any attributes) could be used largely the same way (it, too, has transparent content model in browser practice and in HTML5 CR), but it has some restrictions that make that approach questionable. In particular, by the syntax rules, an `a` element must not contain another `a` element or other “interactive content” like `input`.

Comment: You did understand that fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `<data>` or `<span>` tags

EDIT:
 Alternatively, though it won't constitute valid html, you could come up with your own tags like `<my group>` that you can use to group your elements without any automatic formatting by the browser.

Comment: Neither of them has the semantics of grouping, and neither of them hides its content.

Comment: OP seems to think it's fine. `I don't want anything invisible, as I told I need this for grouping purpose, but the container itself should not be visible on the page or affect it's rendering in any way. table bad, div pad, data and span cool.`

Comment: The `data` and `span` elements are surely visible like the next element. Perhaps the question *really* calls for an element that just causes its content to be rendered but this is not at all what it *says*. And neither `data` nor `span` can have arbitrary content (they cannot contain a heading for example).

Comment: Uh huh? This is not that good then. I hoped to include any tags that could be included into `<body>`.