# Is there a purely logical way of grouping html elements?

Tags: html

`<div>` and `<span>` changes a page layout. Using different attribute values does not help.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean tag without any semantics and without any affects on layout that can be used for assigning attributes (class, style etc) to group of elements.

Comment: This is actually very good question, and very good answer below! I am in web development for over 20 years, and now I'm in a situation where I need the above! I guarantee that 99% of other developers can't understand this, and they have downvoted this, but it's wrong. Question is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer - [Is there any logical container tag in HTMl that I can use for grouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086901/is-there-any-logical-container-tag-in-html-that-i-can-use-for-grouping). There is **NO** such element. Thanks for minuses instead of the answer.